# node.js beginner - why does this receive 2 responses?

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request, response) {
  console.log("Request received.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

console.log("Server has started.");
```

this writes to console on a request from my chrome browser:

Request received
Request received

Two times? Why?

Comment: it is because of the favicon request. I am sorry for not reading the text fully :( it is a saturday and I had wine and beer for dinner :/

Comment: log(request) instead of logging the unhelpful string "Request received" and you can see for yourself that Per was correct. It's always better to log relevant stateful data, not generic debugging strings :)

Comment: Please write an answer for your question and accept it!

Comment: This is a known bug in Chrome, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7904867/133 and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4941800/133

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was your browser asking for favicon.ico