# Node.js weird multiple code execution per request

Tags: node.js

I did some experiment with node earlier

The following code outputs "aaa" to console, and the browser keeps waiting for response, as expected.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  //res.writeHead(200);
  console.log("aaa");
  //res.end("hello");
  //console.log("test111");
  //res.end("bye");
}).listen(5555);
```

Output:

```
aaa
```

But, as soon as I un-comment the first res.end, node writes "aaa" to the console twice on one request!

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  console.log("aaa");
  res.end("hello");
  //console.log("test111");
  //res.end("bye");
}).listen(5555);
```

Output:

```
aaa
aaa
```

Finally, when I un-comment everything,

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  console.log("aaa");
  res.end("hello");
  console.log("test111");
  res.end("bye");
}).listen(5555);
```

Output:

```
aaa
test111
aaa
test111
```

Any idea why the console.log statements are executed twice per single request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example, the browser doesn't get a reply and stops there.

In the second example, the browser *does* get a reply, and then goes on to request the favicon which is a second request.

Try to also log the request url:

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log("aaa", req.url);
  res.end("bye");
}).listen(5555);
```

and you'll see the server going:

```
aaa /
aaa /favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 5):

This has the answer you're looking for:

[NodeJS server incrementing variable by two for every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904867/nodejs-server-incrementing-variable-by-two-for-every-request)

It is hitting / and /favicon.ico.