# Why does a browser send two requests for the same page when it's refreshed?

Tags: http, google-chrome, networking, browser, request

I've created a simple Node.js app which logs to console the current `request.url` for every incoming HTTP request. When I refresh the page in Chrome on Mac OS X ML, I receive two requests for the same page. **Why?**

In comparison, when I use **curl** and request the same page, I receive only one request. Same one request if I refresh the page in Safari.

**Why would Chrome send two requests for the same page?**

**Edit:** I've looked into the `request.headers` and found one difference: the `accept` header.

Here is the header for the first request. Notice, it *accepts* a list of specific mimes.

```
{ host: 'www.pulsr.local:1337',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  'accept-charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
  cookie: 'PULSRSESSID=BBtDAWMVgbQZ8lXA6wv4Wg/vwwI=; PULSRSESSID=dsGxP494UxJueit2/u79AFiM5fw=' }
```

Here is the second request. This time it *accepts everything*.

```
{ host: 'www.pulsr.local:1337',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  'accept-charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
  cookie: 'PULSRSESSID=VGWRSG9zIokHjA2vLa1b+/fUqu8=; PULSRSESSID=dsGxP494UxJueit2/u79AFiM5fw=' }
```

**Edit 2:** I've checked and see that both requests are `GET` requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's to do with this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402) in Chrome where it's sending a request for the favicon on every request. Firefox and other browsers do this on their first request but cache it.

Comment: Good guess, but I've checked that on the very first request it sends 3 requests (2 that I've mentioned + 1 for favicon). After that there are only 2 requests for each page.

Comment: Eventually, I'm inclined to believe that this bug is the cause.

Answer (score 3):

As found in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460661/what-to-do-with-chrome-sending-extra-requests#29231264), it can be caused by empty `src` attributes on images or iframes. I had the same problem : 4 requests on the exact same page — not on the favicon — from Chromium, when doing only 1 page refresh. In my case, I found out it was due to empty `href` attributes on `link` tags :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" />
```

So 1 request for my page reload, and 1 request for each of the 3 above links.

Comment: I know that's like 4 years old, but you just saved my life! I would've never guessed that!

Answer (score 0):

be aware of firebug light extension on chrome .. that was my problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case an iframe with `src="#"` caused page to open twice

```
<iframe src="#" class="iframe lazyload" id="youtube-player-iframe" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```