# AngularJs routing, multiple requests in server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want to use angularjs routing, I'm using but it's making extra requests in server side. Anyone know the solution of this problem, or I'm doing something wrong?

Client app.js

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false})
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/tpl/main.tmp.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
}])

//routes.js
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("test")
    res.render(__dirname+'/public/tpl/index.html', siteConfig)
})
//output
//test
//test
//test
//test
```

Files:

```
models
public
|-css
|-js
|--app.js
|--angular.js
app.js
```

Comment: you get 4 server calls for a single page load?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying this with brand new project.

Comment: is your page actually rendering? I don't see anything here that would cause you to be hitting the server `/` 4 times in one page load, unless it's hitting it for ALL of your server calls, i.e. calls for `.js`, `.css`, etc....

Comment: I'have 4 css and 4 js file but angularjs working, page rendering successfully. I tried it without css files too and just with angularjs-angular-route, still same.

Comment: do you get the same result without the use of html5Mode?

Comment: something is missing here.... There is no reason for angular to make 4 requests to the server for one page, unless there is something on the page making requests that isn't shown here in your snippets.

Comment: Yeah.. Very interesting problem. But I deleted one of the js files, it showed three logs in console, I didn't notice this before.

Comment: I deleted without ngRoute, still same, I should made something wrong.

Comment: Since you are already using angular routing then why are you again trying to render the same page from express, you don't need that. You should assume that with AngularJS in front, Express is not less than a REST engine, you should expose the API and consume it in front end.

Comment: I'm rendering index.html, it calls app.js, then it's rendering main.tmp.html, I don't think this is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A few things may cause this, a closer inspection of both request packets might narrow down the cause. Some ideas to check for:

- The browser keeps trying to fetch the site [favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753148/why-does-a-browser-send-two-requests-for-the-same-page-when-its-refreshed/14753215#14753215) because it can't find one
- Fetching an image [with a # in the URL](http://learn.eastros.com/2015/01/02/why-my-browser-sent-duplicate-requests-to-the-server-for-a-page/) (i.e. `<img src="#"/>`)
- [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag in the HTML
- Web browsers may retry requests when the [connection is closed before receiving a response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4)