# php curl post twice

Tags: php, curl

I know this is duplicate question. I tried all solutions from stackoverflow.com but I could not resolve it.
This is very random behavior. When `php curl post` to destination server api, sometimes same request get posted twice to destination. I checked if source `php` is refreshed, but `php` is not refreshed. Another strange thing I noticed that, I get `curl output` of re-post request only. I don't get `curl output` of first original request.

```
$curl_unit = curl_init($URL);

curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, gethostbyname($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$curl_output = curl_exec($curl_unit);
$code = curl_getinfo($curl_unit, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl_unit);
SaveMyLog("DATA RECEIVED FROM destination: \r\n" . $curl_output . "\r\n Http code response: " . $code . "\r\n");
```

Above mentioned code is general code for `curl` in all `php` pages of the project.
Later I tried different curl code when I found some solutions on stackoverflow. Following is new curl code which is also not working sometimes and same random strange behavior happens.

```
$curl_unit = curl_init($URL);

curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, gethostbyname($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

ob_start(); 
curl_exec($curl_unit);
$code = curl_getinfo($curl_unit, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl_unit);
$curl_output = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean();         

SaveMyLog("DATA RECEIVED FROM destination: \r\n" . $curl_output . "\r\n Http code response: " . $code . "\r\n");
ob_end_flush();
```

Please note `$URL` and `$postdata` is already defined.
`SaveMyLog` function is used for logging purpose.

```
function SaveMyLog($lin, $deprecated = 'mylog.log')
{
    $logid = '';
    $date = getdate();
    $fileName = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
    $file = str_replace('.php', '', $fileName);

    $logfile = $file . "_" . $date['year'] . "-" . $date['mon'] . "-" . $date['mday'] . ".log";

    $fd = fopen('./logs/application_logs/' . $logfile, 'a+');
    fwrite($fd, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . $logid . "\t" . $lin . "\n");
    fclose($fd);
    @chmod('../logs/application_logs/' . $logfile, 0666);
}
```

Comment: How about using TOKENS (in the form for post data) to prevent send twice the form (that can call then 2 times the same url with curl)? Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753148/why-does-a-browser-send-two-requests-for-the-same-page-when-its-refreshed  can be the bug.

Comment: Try setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`. `curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

Comment: This may give you more information: `print curl_error($curl_unit);` - place it after the curl_exec

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I think TOKEN would be useful in case of refresh. But this is not case of refresh.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried `curl_setopt($curl_unit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` but problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a CSRF token, this would get changed after every request.

Answer (score 0):

from your code i see no reason why it should behave in such strange manner.

So there can be some other problem. If you are calling the script from a browser, make sure the browser calls it just once.

[Why does a browser send two requests for the same page when it's refreshed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753148/why-does-a-browser-send-two-requests-for-the-same-page-when-its-refreshed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hi Vody. I have made sure that it is not related with `browser refresh`. If it is a `browser refresh` then I could see all `logs` in printed twice at `source php` where I am calling this curl to destination. However I can see same request getting printed at destination and this is random behavior.

Comment: Hey, just for the sake of completeness, put log also in the beginning of the code. I had similar problem as you are experiencing and it was cause by Safari and the php script was being prematurely terminated. So if you send random numbers throught curl. Your destination will receive 2 requests under 1 random number, right?

Comment: Hi, I could give you logs but I can see logs are printed only once. In logs, I am printing postdata, url and curl output and http code. And yes, destination is receiving 2 requests under 1 random number. This behavior is random.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and we solved it by disabling or uninstalling the Firebug Lite extension.