# IHttpHandler execute twice on chrome

Tags: c#

Environment :

1. Visual Studio 2008
2. Fiddler2

IHttpHandler execute twice on chrome ,

I've been stuck on this problem for hours at this point and I can't figure out the problem.

i have a IHttpHandler as below ,

```
 public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

when i execute it on chrome , it will send second requests

[the image link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23971112/ihttphandler%20question.JPG)

if i execute it on IE8 , it only send one request

[the image link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23971112/ihttphandler%20question2.JPG)

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you might be experiencing a known issue/feature of Chrome: [What to do with chrome sending extra requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4460661/718972) Do you have any plugins or extensions running?

Comment: thanks for your suggest , i found its caused by Chrome extension ...