# Rendering out a JSON reponse to HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**JSON object:**

```
{"id":75,"year":2011,"make":"Aston Martin","model":"V12 Vanquish"}
```

**jQuery:**

```
function post() {
  $("form").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    $.each(json, function(k, v) {
      $("#vehicle_record").append('<li class="'+k+'">'+v+'</li>');
    });
  });
}
```

**HTML page output:**

```
75
2011
Aston Martin
V12 Vanquish
75
2011
Aston Martin
V12 Vanquish
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is the output rendered twice? (I only expect it once)
2. Is there a better way to render JSON to the page? (please advise)

**--UPDATE--**

The following a walk through of the UX: 
FORM ONE: name > *click next* > `post` > FORM TWO > Choose Vehicle > *click next* > `post` > see vehicle picked: add another vehicle? Y (BACK to FORM TWO) / N (continue...)

I need to be able to use `post` for each model independently without interference. So how do I get for example all of the JSON objects submitted to the vehicle model? (I need this post function to be modular)

Perhaps I can do something like this?:

```
function post() {
  $("form").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var model = e.currentTarget.action;
    renderOnPage(json, model);
  });
}
function renderOnPage(data, model) {
  if ( model.match(/vehicles/) ) {
  $.each(data, function(k, v) {
    $("#vehicle_record").append('<li class="'+k+'">'+v+'</li>');
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like the method `post` was called twice!!!

Comment: What's the `ajax:success` event? That's not a standard jQuery event, AFAIK.

Comment: can you add a console logging in the post method as the first line and see how many times it is called

Comment: Also put it in the callback function, to see if something is triggering the event twice.

Comment: re rendering json ( client side templating ) if you don't want to make something,  I like **ejs** ( simple ) and **linkedins fork of dust** ( if you need logic templating )

Comment: Ok so yes `post` is called twice and JSON is returned but for two different models. I will update my question.

Comment: Recommend if that's the case that you call `$("#vehicle_record").empty();` inside the success before the loop - however, you may still get inconsistent results if the events overlap

Comment: @Rick calling empty() is not a good solution to the problem but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that the Ajax calls occurs twice.
If Chrome is used, there may be a Chrome extension involved that causes this problem. See the post below for a similar situation: [IHttpHandler execute twice on chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520070/ihttphandler-execute-twice-on-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `post` function actually binds a handler twice to `success` event, therefore its obvious it's been executed twice. You don't actually need to call function explicitly I suppose. Simply

```
$("form").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    $.each(json, function(k, v) {
      $("#vehicle_record").append('<li class="'+k+'">'+v+'</li>');
    });
});
```

would work. Don't call `post` on clicks

Answer (score 1):

Better or maybe best way to render JSON on HTML (without using third party libraries) is to come up with something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<span>ID</span>: <span json-path="id"></span>
<span>Year</span>: <span json-path="year"></span>
<span>Make</span>: <span json-path="make"></span>
<span>Model</span>: <span json-path="model"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

where json-path is just any attribute name that you want to come up with. 
Now on success of AJAX you should do something like this:

```
function refreshPage(data) {
   $("[json-path]", $(document)).each(function() {
    $(this).text(data[$(this).attr("json-path")]);
   });
}
```

Now if you need more complex features like to display an array of items ins JSON in a table or LIST then just add a switch case statement in above refreshPage

```
 switch((this).prop('tagName')) {
        case "INPUT":
           $(this).val(data[$(this).attr("json-path")])
```

Using this approach you can even map your json-path to an array on JSON path for a TABLE or SELECT tag and then use switch case to identify and render each type of elements differently.

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion could you perhaps share a link with a thorough example of your suggested implementation. Thanks again.