# Chrome - multiple requests

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I send a GET-request to my webapp using chrome, according to my apache access log two identical requests (not always, but most of the times, I can't reproduce it - it's not for the favicon) get send to the sever, although only one is shown in the chrome dev tools. I deactivated all extensions and it's still happening.

Is this https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1872177 true and is it a chrome feature or should I dig deeper within my app to find the bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's even worse than that. My experience here (developing with Google App Engine), is that Chrome is making all kinds of extra requests.

This is possibly due to the option that is in the Settings, checked by default:

- **Predict network actions to improve page load performance**

Here is a really weird example: my website's page runs a notifications check every 15 seconds (done in javascript). Even after closing all tabs related to my website, I see requests coming from my IP, some random pages but also the notification check request. To me that means that Chrome has a page of my website running in the background and is even evaluating its javascript.

When I request a page, I pretty much always get another request for one of the links in that page. And it also requests resources of the extra pages (.css, .js, .png files). Lots of requests going on.

I have seen the same behavior with the development server that runs locally.

Happens also from another computer / network.
Doesn't happen with Firefox.

Also, see [What to do with chrome sending extra requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460661/what-to-do-with-chrome-sending-extra-requests)

Comment: How do we handle this in Server side? I'm Loading a png file for Hit counter and it is giving me wrong count due to this.