# rescue_from being executed twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, exception

I am attempting to rescue RuntimeErrors from within my controller using rescue_from, log it as a HealthNotice, and then redirect the user with a flash message, but I'm finding that in certain circumstances, the rescue_from method is being run twice (I end up with 2 duplicate HealthNotices).  If the exception is rasied from a function called in a method (such as the test method below), it only creates one, but if I raise the exception directly within the method (such as test2), the rescue function is running twice (although strangely I don't get a double render error -- ??)

```
class Portal::BluerimController < PortalController
    rescue_from RuntimeError, with: :error_handler
    def error_handler(e)
      hn_long_message = "#{e.class}: #{e.message}\n#{e.backtrace.join("\n")}\n\nPARAMS:\n#{params}"
      HealthNotice.create(name: "API Exception Handled", severity: "WARNING", short_message: e.message, long_message: hn_long_message)
      flash[:notice] = e.message
      redirect_to :action => :index and return
    end

    def test
      Sotal.new.test  # a method that raises a RuntimeError -- only 1 HealthNotice
    end

    def test2
      raise "an error"  # results in duplicate HealthNotice
    end
end
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't make sense, can you add the logs showing from the request for `test2`, and also add your `config/routes.rb` and both `PortalController` and `ApplicationController`

Comment: not very easily -- PortalController is ~3500 lines long.  Can you advise what sort of thing I should try to look for in there?
When I watch the logs, I'm basically seeing two GET requests back to back for the same action (and subsequent HealthNotice create, and redirection)

Comment: Let's start with the logs and routes then.

Comment: For whatever reason, this is only happening when I use chrome.  If I hit the test action with IE, it redirects OK and only creates 1 HealthNotice.  also, SOME of the time, chrome works as expected as well.  It definitely seems to be an issue of multiple requests hitting the test action in sequence.  I think I'm running up against the issue mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460661/what-to-do-with-chrome-sending-extra-requests

Comment: I can confirm that if I turn off  "Prefetch resources to load pages more quickly.” under chrome settings -> advanced -> privacy, the issue goes away.  I'm kind of surprised I've never run into this issue before, but I also don't know of a good way to handle it in my scenario..

Comment: Well, if a browser (or anything) is requesting the page twice then your app is correctly logging two requests.