# What could be the reason to hit page_load more than once

Tags: asp.net

When I click the Button I am loading one page. i am having some controls in the page_load.

but the problem is my page_load is hitting more than once.

Please can any body explain me what could be the possible reasons for hitting the page_load multiple times.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is hitting `Page_Load` twice your issue?

Most probably its due to  `asp:Image` or `img` without `src` defined.

To quote [mbanavige of ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1664789.aspx#4349335),

> if you have an img tag with an empty/missing src attribute, then the
> browser may re-request the current page (or may request the default
> page) why trying to satisfy the empty src for that img tag.
>
> Another possibility that occurs from time to time is that the
> page_load event has been wired up twice.

Related: [page loads twice in Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009092/page-loads-twice-in-google-chrome)

Comment: What do you want me to do if I have something like this in my page.<%--           <Background  BackgroundImageUrl="SPREADCLIENTPATH:/img/cbbg.gif"></Background>--%>

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. In the page life-cycle it is called on the initial request and on the postback.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET webforms are self-posting, so Page_Load will hit hit everytime a time a post back occurs. If you would like to only execute certain code on initial page load, add the following to your Load event handler:

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
 // Code here
}
```

This says only execute this code if this is the first request to this page.

Comment: But second time also its saying Ispostback is true.

Comment: The second time IsPostBack *will* be true.