# Pageload event occures twice in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I am facing very strange issue , that in one of my page pageload event handled 2 times , there is no any code that will make this 2nd pageload, what should be the problem with this page, please give your views if you have found similar issue in your development life!

**Update :**

I have checked with different browsers and found that this issue occurs only with **Chrome**

Thanks.

Comment: Is there code on your page load? If you are using IE theres a flicker occurs during pageload.

Comment: can you post the code where your event handler of page_load is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to chrome request Favicon.ico. I got this problem when i out watch on **Request.URL**  through debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, that you have `AutoEventWireUp` set to true and at the same time you're subscribing to the event explicitly: `this.Load += Page_Load;`.

So, either set `AutoEventWireUp` in `@Page` directive to false or remove explicit subscription.

For more information on `AutoEvetWireUp`: http://forums.asp.net/p/932513/1096656.aspx

Comment: If i make Autoeventwireup = false then my controls will not bind (remain empty), i have not handled page_load explicitly

Comment: That's quiet interesting. Could you please show the code of the page or Page_Load handler?

Comment: This issue is only with chrome , i could not post whole page code here

Comment: Did you look for solution which I wrote as last answer?

Answer (score 0):

set AutoEventWireup="false".......

Answer (score 0):

I had identical issue on my web page.

Source of that issue was empty `"src"` in images on page. Try to look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009092/page-loads-twice-in-google-chrome) thread.

Mariusz

Answer (score 0):

It's a Chrome bug.  Some say that it has to do with "Favicon.ico" (See also https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64810 )

The issue does not present itself in FF or IE.

It's NOT a JS issue.  I encountered the same issue with pages that add entries to a database log: when that page is invoked with Chrome (but not FF or IE), the log appears twice :(