# Google Chrome sends 2 requests to every controller/ razor page

Tags: c#, google-chrome

For some reason, Google Chrome sends 2 requests to every webpage on my solution. I originally experienced this issue on an MVC web application but then I made a test project without using MVC and this continued to happen.

This does not happen with Edge or Internet Explorer.

Did anybody experience the same problem and how did you go about it?

Most of my research pointed in the direction of having an href="#" tag that would cause the browser to reload the page but this is not the case in my situation.

This normally would not be an issue, but it seems to be causing the AntiForgeryRequestToken to not get validated

Comment: Check to see whether or not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009092/page-loads-twice-in-google-chrome) solves your problem

Comment: Are they identical requests or is one maybe a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

**2 requests** means the total SAME requests or an 'OPTIONS' method and a normal medthod?

if you are in the **second** situation, you will need use IIS/ngnix to Url Rewrite to make sure your chrome Url and your ajax request url are in the same domain.