# Chrome runs PHP script twice when press Enter in Address Bar

Tags: php, google-chrome

A very odd glitch I've encountered recently. I run Chrome Version 98.0.4758.81 (Official Build) (64-bit) (first noticed issue on v.97). When I run my PHP script for the first time by entering URL - it runs 1 time. When I press RELOAD button - it runs one time too. But when I put cursor to Adress bar with needed URL already there and press ENTER - script runs 2 times. Disabling pages prefetching does not help. No session_start(), html etc. Pure php script that works with BD and executes in 12-15 seconds (each run). Edge works fine - when I RELOAD or press ENTER.

So, here is the code that runs 2 times, when I press ENTER in adress BAR

```
<?php
include_once('/home/alex/public_html/dev/config.inc.php'); // just varibles
$conni = mysqli_connect("", $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
mysqli_query($conni,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($conni,"SET CHARACTER_SET 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
mysqli_query($conni,"INSERT INTO tmp (`tm`,`user`) VALUES ('2','".date ("Y-m-d H:i:s")."');");
sleep (10);
?>
```

[image: And here is result in PHPMyadmin]

Comment: I have never experienced this as a Chrome user. I suspect something different, like a redirect without the script halting. That happens when you don't put `exit;` after `header('Location: ...');` for example.

Comment: could be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009092/page-loads-twice-in-google-chrome ?

Comment: Good scenario in that QA. It's not a Chrome issue but something with your routes/redirects/isolation of processing

Comment: @Marcel Preda. Nope. Absolutely not.

Comment: @Daniel W. Good guess. But it doesn't explain working Reload, first run and no such glitch in Edge

Comment: @dMole any plugins in chrome? What happens when you look at the tools( F12). You can persist the logs there - might be 2 records? Also what happens when you just have a vanilla php page, i.e just try and do an echo and then a die() after that mysqli_query

Comment: You can also check it from Incognito tab

Comment: @Richard Housham. Removing Sleep(10) makes only 1 record in DB. What I found out using F12 - page runs 2 times - first one is 301 redirect on self. Second one - 200 - ok.

Comment: 301 = moved perminantly - is there any header code afterwards somewhere?

Comment: Nope. Just 301 - Moved Permanently. And runs again same page with 200 - ok. I made a request to hoster. Hope he will give some explanation.

Comment: That's definitely your server and not Chrome. The difference between browsers is the caching. "Moved Permanently" offen gets cached in browsers. Then there is a difference between hard-reload and soft-reload. What URL the redirects point to?

Comment: https://www.mmcs.com.ua/dev/tmp.php After link opens - try to press ENTER in adress bar